# ownership chaining not working with sp_cursorfetch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

ownership chaining is not working for me in some cases. I use Microsoft SQL Server 14.0.3370.1.

This is the setup for my tests:

```
create function fnTest() returns int
begin
    return 3
end
go

create table tblTest
(
    Number1 int
)
go

insert into tblTest (Number1)
values (5)
go

create view vwTest
as
select
    tblTest.Number1,
    dbo.fnTest() as Number2
from tblTest
go

create view vwTest2
as
select
    dbo.fnTest() as Number2
go

grant select on vwTest to test
go

grant select on vwTest2 to test
go
```

Running the following commands as user `test` works fine:

```
select * from vwTest
```

```
select * from vwTest2
```

```
declare @p1 int
exec sp_cursoropen @p1 output,N'select * from vwTest2'
exec sp_cursorfetch @p1
```

But this command is not working:

```
declare @p1 int
exec sp_cursoropen @p1 output,N'select * from vwTest'
exec sp_cursorfetch @p1
```

I get the following error:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'fnTest', database 'Test' schema 'dbo'.
```

If I grant explicit permissions on the function fnTest, the error message is gone.

Why does ownership chaining not work in this case?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be peculiar to **keyset** cursors, where ownership chaining does not work as expected for scalar functions in the fetch portion of the cursor plan.

The issue is not limited to API cursors. I have adjusted your demo slightly to work with a T-SQL cursor and permit dynamic, keyset, and static implementations:

#### Setup

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.vwTest;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.fnTest;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tblTest;
DROP USER IF EXISTS test;
```

```
CREATE USER test WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnTest() 
RETURNS integer 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 3;
END;
go
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblTest
(
    Number1 integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
GO  
INSERT dbo.tblTest 
    (Number1)
VALUES 
    (5);
GO  
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwTest 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    T.Number1,
    dbo.fnTest() AS Number2
FROM dbo.tblTest AS T;
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.vwTest TO test;
GRANT SHOWPLAN TO test;
```

#### Test

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO
EXECUTE AS USER = 'test';

-- Works as a plain SELECT
SELECT VT.Number1, VT.Number2 
FROM dbo.vwTest AS VT;

-- Fails as a keyset cursor only (dynamic and static are fine)
DECLARE c CURSOR 
    LOCAL
    --DYNAMIC
    KEYSET 
    --STATIC
    READ_ONLY 
    TYPE_WARNING 
    FOR
    SELECT VT.Number1, VT.Number2 
    FROM dbo.vwTest AS VT;

OPEN c;

BEGIN TRY
    FETCH c;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;

REVERT;
```

The test produces the permissions error only when a keyset cursor is used:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'fnTest', database 'Sandpit', schema 'dbo'.

#### Cursor plans

There are two plans associated with a cursor, the *population* plan and the *fetch* plan.

The population plan runs on `OPEN` to populate any cursor work table needed.

For a static cursor, the work table contains the entire result set. For a keyset cursor, only the keys of the relation(s) are stored. A dynamic cursor does not use a work table so there is no population plan.

The fetch plan runs on each call to fetch a row (or batch of rows in the case of an API cursor).

##### Static plan

[image: static cursor plan]

No permission error occurs. Ownership chaining from the view works as expected for both the table and the function, as shown by a trace on the [Audit Schema Object Access Event Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-schema-object-access-event-class) profiling event:

[image: Permission checks for static cursor]

Permissions are checked on the view first, followed by the function, then the table. The permission checked on the view and table is `SELECT` (1). The permission checked on the function is `EXECUTE` (32) as documented.

No permissions are checked on the `FETCH` statement because it retrieves data only from the cursor work table.

##### Dynamic plan

[image: dynamic cursor plan]

No permission error occurs. Ownership chaining from the view works as expected for both the table and the function:

[image: Permission checks for dynamic cursor]

Permissions are successfully checked on the view, table, and function for `DECLARE CURSOR`, `OPEN`, and `FETCH`.

##### Keyset plan

[image: keyset cursor plan]

Permissions are successfully checked on the view, table, and function for `DECLARE CURSOR` and `OPEN`. Permissions are also successfully checked on the view for the `FETCH` statement, but a permission error occurs when checking the function:

[image: Permission checks for keyset cursor]

There is no particular reason I can see for this to work differently for keyset cursors, so it seems to be a product defect. Tested on SQL Server 2019 CU 15.

#### Workaround

Use either static or dynamic instead of a keyset when relying on ownership chaining to access a function through a cursor.

You can specify which cursor types are acceptable in the call to [`sp_cursoropen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-cursoropen-transact-sql) via the *scrollopt* optional parameter:

> [image]

The server happens to choose a static cursor for your select from vwTest2, but a keyset cursor for vwTest.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. In my case, the cursor comes from from the Mail Merge function in Microsoft Word, so I can not influence the creation of the cursor. But I am fine with granting execution permissions on the used functions.

I was just puzzled why the cursor would fail, since I did not find any documentation on such a limitation.